# Armature doesn't move mesh all the way; mesh only slightly deforms

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting

My brother made a fairly simple 3d model using Zbrush, and I've been trying to armature it for a bothersome period of time. He built an armature and I've assigned the vertex groups with weight paint. I can deform the torso quite well with minimal tearing, but when I attempt to move the arms, the mesh follows the armature slowly and nonuniformly; it ends up looking like a snake. I wasn't able to find any threads online with the same problem. I tried asking ChatGPT, but it was unable to provide me with a satisfactory answer.

I parented the mesh to the skeleton using automatic weights, but, since the automatic weight function never works for me, I then used weight paint. After painting the vertex groups, I used an armature modifier set to modify using vertex groups only.

Unlike most of the people with similar issues, I've actually been using Blender for a while, but I've only ever gotten armatures to work properly two times in my life. I've had problems like this with some of my other models as well, so any help clearing this up once and for all would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Fishman prior to deformation]

[image: I move the bone....and problems ensue]

Comment: Hello, have you checked the normal orientation? If it's still not your problem, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I'm trying to add my file to this post, but it's 35 mb, and Blend-exchange won't let me, as their maximum file size is 30 mb. does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: use workupload for example and share the link here

Comment: I checked my normals, and they all seem to be ship-shape, i.e. they're all facing outward. I'll keep trying to upload my file.

Comment: Apart from the mentioned normals problem, you might have lots of duplicate geometry which can cause armature parenting to fail. In Edit mode, select All then hit M > Merge by Distance and see if the status bar shows lots of vertices deleted.

Comment: Here is my file. The password is "banana"

Comment: All we want now is a link to it...

Comment: Oh my gosh.....I seriously forgot to link it? hahahah sorry https://workupload.com/file/yZ7RnHALCsW

Comment: The password is "banana"

Comment: Not looked at it closely, but for starters the Scale hasn't been applied to the model (Ctrl-A > Scale) and the number of bones and naming convention for each side of the armature don't match. When you try to parent it there's a long delay and you'll see a Bone heat weighting warning in the bottom status bar which is a sure sign that all isn't well!

Comment: There are some problems with your mesh (intersecting faces for example) plus it's very dense, which is not great for rigging, you should first model a low-poly version, if you don't want loose some details, just bake the normals of the high-poly. At the end, as John says, don't forget to apply the scale and rotation

Comment: thanks, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Ok I did some tests and a low-poly version of a similar model actually works! Thanks so much; I would have never thought of that!